# How can i pass a program name throgh php to a to a shell script file?

Tags: php, html, shell

Through HTML file I am sending a file name to where I am running a shell script. I want to send that file name to shell script as an argument.
`$prg1=$_POST['prg1'];`
this file I am importing from user input.
`shell_exec('./shell.sh')`
and in this script I want to send that file .
any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `escapeshellarg` to add appropriate quoting, and then concatenate it as an argument to the script.

```
shell_exec('./shell.sh ' . escapeshellarg($prg1));
```

The script can then get the argument as `$1`.

For multiple arguments, separate them with space:

```
shell_exec('./shell.sh ' . escapeshellarg($prg1) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($prg2) . ' ' . escapeshellarg($prg3) );
```

Comment: What is the syntax for passing multiple arguments.? @Barmar

Comment: Separate them with spaces in the command line, just like when you're typing to the shell.